# Avoid reassigning owner in the case

Tags: case, assignment-rules, service

We have active assignment rule in our organization to assign the case to queue.

Assignment rule is,
[image]

Whenever case matches this rule it gets assigned to particular queue. But when changed the case owner from queue to particular user with field Project is true it gets reassigned to same queue. How can I change this rule in such way to avoid reassigning.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add another filter which can stop your assignment rule to fire everytime. For example, you donot want to fire this rule when case owner changes but project__c is true, change your assignment rule criteria to "Formula evaluates to true" and use below:

```
PRIORVALUE(OwnerId) <> OwnerId && Project__c
```

If you want to run your assignment rule only during creation of case use this formula.. `ISNEW() && Project__c`

Comment: It seems not working. Here is my formula with yours... (caseProject__c = TRUE) && (PRIORVALUE(OwnerId) <> OwnerId && caseProject__c = TRUE)

Comment: You are using case.project__c condition twice.. Only once should be good

Comment: I changed but no luck..(caseProject__c = TRUE) && (PRIORVALUE(OwnerId) <> OwnerId)

Comment: Are you getting error with formula field saving or are you not seeing expected result?

Comment: am not seeing expected result

Comment: When case is incoming it will check for the assignment rules and if the Project field is true it will assign queue to the case. After some time when case is assigned to particular user from queue with the project field is true, it is keep reassigning to Queue.

Comment: If you want to run your assignment rule only during creation of case use this formula.. `ISNEW() && Project__c`